# Autowire list of beans of a type in Grails

Tags: spring, grails, autowired

I am trying to autowire a list of beans of a given type into my `Bootstrap.groovy`.

Say, I have the below interface and classes.

```
interface Vehicle {
}

@Component
class Car implements Vehicle {
    boolean byName = false
}

@Component
class Van implements Vehicle {
    boolean byName = false
}
```

And my `Bootstrap.groovy` looks like this:

```
class Bootstrap {
    List<Vehicle> vehicles

    def init = { servletContext ->
        println "Vehicles are ${vehicles}" // prints null
    }
}
```

I am sure I have set up component scanning correctly as I can see normal beans being wired up. However, it looks like autowiring by type isn't happening, causing the Spring container to try to wire the list of `Vehicle`s by name and failing in the process.

Any insights would be appreciated.

I am using Grails 2.4.3

Comment: Have you tried "def vehicles" in place of List<Vehicle> vehicles?

Comment: @Abdullah I don't see how that can solve the problem. (I have tried it)

Comment: if all fails, there is always `getBeansOfType`

Comment: Can we see your configuration for component scanning? Typically you would build a rule of the sort "*Vehicle.groovy" and have classes named CarVehicle and VanVehicle if you are going to do it by name. Perhaps you want to autowire by type instead.

Comment: Yes. I want to do autowire by type. That's what my question says. However, Grails autowires by name by default and it is too precious about it apparently.

Comment: Also, why are you expecting the List<Vehicle> to be injected? Usually you inject bean instances, not a list of beans associated by base type. You would need to query the list of registered beans and build such a list manually.

Comment: You can specify autowire="byType" in your bean definition. Either you are doing explicit bean definitions in your conf/spring/resources.groovy file or you are going all the way and defining a new Grails artefact type and picking up the artefacts automatically. You need to read section 18 of the manual carefully. It is a little confusing on the first read. The details are all there though.

Comment: Sorry ... my bad. I didn't see the @Component annotations when I first looked at it. Its not the normal Grails way of doing bean definitions. You are right about the autowiring. Grails components are defined to be autowire by name. You can change your own components to something else, but you are stuck with bootstrap. The recommendation by cfrick to use getBeansOfType is probably the way to go.